# How can you apply the Adapter Pattern to a Collection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, collections, .net-2.0, adapter

> Given the two classes below, how can I
>   convert `List<Person>` to
>   `List<Person2>`?

**EDIT:** This is a fabricated example. The point I'm trying to make is that I can't modify the `Person` class, and we'll know `arbitraryNumber` when we instantiate `List<Person2>`.

**EDIT2:** I know that many of you will find this unbelievable, but this code will be deployed to a Windows-Server-2000 machine, which means that it must work with .NET 2.0. [Yes - I find this to be unbelievable as well.]

```
public class Person
{
    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
}

public class Person2 : Person
{
    private readonly int _arbitraryNumber;
    public Person2(int arbitraryNumber)
    {
        _arbitraryNumber = arbitraryNumber;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0}, {1} - {2}", LastName, FirstName, _arbitraryNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with doing such a conversion? It appears to be a simple thing, so I would like to know what difficulties you are having.

Comment: Person2 does not look like an adapter to me. Person2 should contain an instance of Person. Perhaps by having a Person field and taking a Person in the constructor.

Comment: How would you know what arbitrary number to use when creating a `Person2` from a `Person`?

Comment: @Oded: You're right. It was an easy problem. I should've finished my morning coffee first. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Person2 needs to change to be an adapter. Something like this

```
public class Person2
{
    private readonly int _arbitraryNumber;
    private readonly Person _person;
    public Person2(Person person, int arbitraryNumber)
    {
        _arbitraryNumber = arbitraryNumber;
        _person = person;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0}, {1} - {2}", _person.LastName, _person.FirstName, _arbitraryNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the adapter on the collection is easier.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
// put some people in it.
var person2s = persons.Select(p => new Person2(4, p)); // 4 chosen arbitrarily
```

Or for .NET 2

```
List<Person2> person2s = new List<Person2>();
foreach (Person p in persons)
{
    Person2 person2 = new Person2(p, 11); // 11 arbitrarily chosen by asking a kid for a number
    person2s.Add(person2);
}
```

Comment: Correct - But if you can believe it - I'm working with .NET 2.0. :)

Comment: +1 for implementing adapter pattern correctly, thus making conversion trivial